# Inserting rows into a MySQL table based on a query

Tags: sql, mysql, insert

I have a query

```
SELECT A.a, A.b, A.c
FROM A
LEFT JOIN X ON A.a = X.x
WHERE X.x IS NULL
```

which finds entries in table A which have no corresponding entry in table X.  How can I insert the results of this query into table X?  If I had only a few entries I would do

```
INSERT INTO X(xa, xb, xc)
VALUES ('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2')
```

(As an aside: the column d is set to auto_increment; does that do the right thing if I run the above?  Similarly, columns e, f, ..., h have default values; I trust these will be set accordingly.)

This would not be hard to do by exporting, writing individual SQL snippets for each row in Excel, and executing each; I ask this mainly to learn SQL better.

(Of course my real table has many more fields and various complications, but I think this simplification will suffice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO X (xa, xb, xc) 
   SELECT A.a, A.b, A.c
     FROM A
LEFT JOIN X ON A.a = X.x
    WHERE X.x IS NULL
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work because the select references the table he's inserting into.

Comment: @Cfreak: `X` is not the same table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO X(xa, xb, xc)
SELECT A.a, A.b, A.c
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN X ON A.a = X.x
 WHERE X.x IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax. But you'll have to use a temporary table as you can't insert into a table you join in your select statement.

```
create temporary table Y like X;
INSERT INTO Y (x,y,z) SELECT a,b,c FROM A LEFT JOIN X ON a=x;
INSERT INTO X SELECT * FROM Y;
```